# In a JCL proc, how to test whether a parameter was not set by the caller?

Tags: jcl

I want to provide default values for parameters in a proc, and for such I want to know how to test whether the EXEC call defined the expected parameters or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out the right way to do this:

```
//MYPROC  PROC  MYPAR=999
//*       [your proc code]
//        PEND
```

If the calling EXEC does not set MYPAR to something (nor nullifies it), it will default to 999 as specified.

Reference: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLTBW_2.1.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r1.ieab600/iea3b6_Examples_of_the_PROC_statement.htm

Answer (score 2):

One technique is to make the default values in your cataloged procedure create JCL errors, thus ensuring the execution JCL supplies a valid value.

```
//AEIOU   PROC DSNHLQ='SUPPLY_A_DSN_HLQ'  Force EXEC statement override
//*
//NOTHING  EXEC PGM=IEFBR14
//DD001    DD  DISP=OLD,DSN=&DSNHLQ..TEMP
```

Another technique is to write a trivial program to validate arbitrary parameters, in COBOL terms you take in the parm value via the Linkage Section and validate against a set of valid values read in from a flat file.  Depending on your SORT product, you may be able to accomplish the same goal with some creative use of control cards.